Stepper motor timing steps
I am building a system using a raspberry pi 4 with a waveshare stepper hat that will control two stepper motors on lenses. 1 is an iris which opens according to steps and the other a flap. The flap is just open and close so no issues with the control and movement of the flap stepper but for the iris I attempted to do small steps up to 5800 over 120 seconds but the stepper wouldn't move enough with steps of about 5 at a time and have experimented and so need to do a burst of say 200 at a time. But still need it to open gradually over the 120 seconds. An approximate 4 second pause should allow for 29 sets of 200 steps.
The GUI shows a counter counting down the timer for user info and so i want to add a time delay between each burst of 200 steps without affecting the countdown. I have had the timer working correctly but not succesful in showing the timer countdown on screen and stepping motor together.
    

def step_open_iris(self):
        
        self.step_size = 200
        if self.step_count<self.openingsize:
                self.t1 = Timer(4, self.delaytimer)
                self.t1.start()
                Motor2.SetMicroStep('hardward' ,'fullstep')    
                Motor2.TurnStep(Dir='backward', steps=self.step_size, stepdelay=0.005)
                self.step_count = self.step_count + self.step_size
                self.showSteps()
                Motor2.Stop()
         


Any assistance would be appreciated before I tear all my hair out!
I have created the GUI with start button and text boxes to set time and steps and a start button. I have added a thread for a timer as a means of producing a gap inbetween the 200 steps at a time. But it goes through the steps quickly so it does the 5800 steps in about 6 seconds and the timer continues then to countdown

Please provide a [mre]. Also note that if the purpose of the Timer is to delay the call to delaytimer and that function also deals with UI, then your approach is invalid, as UI elements are not thread-safe and should never be accessed from external threads (which is what Timer does). Use QTimer instead.
